# FieldUpdated event not updating the field properly on Bills and Adjustment screen

Tags: c#, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I have a DAC called VendorAccountMapping and tried to the field of AP Account in Bills and Adjustments screen via this code:

```
    public class APInvoiceEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    //protected void APInvoice_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    protected void _(Events.FieldUpdated<APInvoice, APInvoice.vendorID> e)
    {
        APInvoice row = (APInvoice)e.Row;

        VendorAccountMapping vendorAccountMapping = SelectFrom<VendorAccountMapping>.Where<VendorAccountMapping.vendorID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>.And<VendorAccountMapping.branchID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>>.View.Select(this.Base, row.VendorID, row.BranchID);
        if (vendorAccountMapping != null)
        {
            row.APAccountID = vendorAccountMapping.APAcctID;
        }
    }
}
```

Weirdly enough, the above piece of code does not work but I have tried the similar piece of code as shown below for Checks and Payments screen and it works without any issues:

```
    public class APPaymentEntry_Extension : PXGraphExtension<APPaymentEntry>
{
    //protected void APPayment_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
    protected void _(Events.FieldUpdated<APPayment, APPayment.vendorID> e)
    {
        APPayment row = (APPayment)e.Row;
        VendorAccountMapping vendorAccountMapping = SelectFrom<VendorAccountMapping>.Where<VendorAccountMapping.vendorID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>.And<VendorAccountMapping.branchID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>>.View.Select(this.Base, row.VendorID, row.BranchID);
        if (vendorAccountMapping != null)
        {
            row.APAccountID = vendorAccountMapping.APAcctID;
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone assist on why it behaves differently for APInvoice?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure right off why one works and the other does not, but I do see that in my version of code that both base graphs already have a VendorID_FieldUpdated event.  You should override those field updated events and call the base events.  Here is one example, but both events you showed should be handled in a similar manner.

```
protected void APInvoice_VendorID_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e, PXFieldUpdated baseEvent)
{
    // Call Base
    if (baseEvent != null) baseEvent.Invoke(cache, e);

    APInvoice row = (APInvoice)e.Row;
    APInvoice rowFromBaseEvent = Base.Document.Locate(row);
    if (rowFromBaseEvent != null) row = rowFromBaseEvent;

    VendorAccountMapping vendorAccountMapping = SelectFrom<VendorAccountMapping>.Where<VendorAccountMapping.vendorID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>.And<VendorAccountMapping.branchID.IsEqual<@P.AsInt>>>.View.Select(this.Base, row.VendorID, row.BranchID);
    if (vendorAccountMapping != null)
    {
        row.APAccountID = vendorAccountMapping.APAcctID;
    }
}
```

In your case, I suspect you want to override a value that could have been set in the base event (already or someday in the future).  I see a APInvoice_APAccountID_FieldDefaulting event and reference to call the event in APInvoiceEntry, so you may need to look deeper.  Therefore, I called the base event first and then located the modified row in the cache to continue on with your customization.

It's possible that no matter what you do here, something else is rewriting the value after your event override executes, so running a debug to step through your code may be the best way to see what's really happening.  It could be that you need to override the FieldDefaulting event of APAccountID to override how it defaults (and is re-defaulted later).  (Hint:  The base event for VendorID Field Updated DOES call SetDefaultsAfterVendorIDChanging which fires the re-default of your field.)